# Tikz Graph Position in Research Paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I am using a tikz environment for drawing result graphs. After running the code graph are drawn at the bottom of the research paper after Reference heading, but in latex code for graph is inserted in between the research paper.

So, how to position graph in between research paper at their appropriate location.

```
\begin{figure}\small
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.57\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Migration Time (Seconds)},
            ylabel={Bandwidth Transfer Rate (Mbps)},
            xmin=0, xmax=50,
            ymin=0, ymax=550,
            xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50},
            tick={0,100,200,300,400,500,550},
            legend pos=north west,
            %ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            ]
            \addplot+[
            color=blue,
            mark size=50pt,
            mark=solid,
            style={ultra thick},
            ]
            coordinates {
                (14.551,100)
                (0,100)(10,100)(20,100)(30,100)(40,100) (50,100)};
            \legend{Idle VM}
            %\addlegendentry{Downtime:232ms}
            %\addplot [variable=\t,samples=200,domain=0:360] ({0.950052*cos(t)},{0.945021*sin(t)});
            %\addlegendentry{Parametric analytic}
            %\legend{Downtime:233ms}
            %\draw[blue] (axis cs: 28,131) -- (axis cs: 28,131)node[anchor=east,rotate=90]{Some label};
            %\draw (axis cs:28,axis cs:131);

            %\addplot[solid, purple, latex-latex]
            %coordinates{(28,0) (28,131)};

            \addplot[color=purple,mark=triangle*,mark size=2,style={thick},mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                (14.551,0)
                (14.551,100)
            };
            \node at (axis cs:38,500) {Downtime: 144 ms};

            %title={Fig. 1.Live Migration Process with Bw=131Mbps},
            \end{axis}
            %title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},

            \end{tikzpicture}
            \subcaption{Live Migration Process with Bw= 100 Mbps}\label{fig:10a}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.57\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Migration Time (Seconds)},
            ylabel={Bandwidth Transfer Rate (Mbps)},
            xmin=0, xmax=50,
            ymin=0, ymax=550,
            xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50},
            tick={0,100,200,300,400,500,550},
            legend pos=north west,
            %ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            ]

            \addplot+[
            color=blue,
            mark size=50pt,
            mark=solid,
            style={ultra thick},
            ]
            coordinates {
                (11.124,200)
                (0,200)(10,200)(20,200)(30,200)(40,200) (50,200)};
            \legend{Idle VM}
            %\addlegendentry{Downtime:232ms}
            %\addplot [variable=\t,samples=200,domain=0:360] ({0.950052*cos(t)},{0.945021*sin(t)});
            %\addlegendentry{Parametric analytic}
            %\legend{Downtime:233ms}
            %\draw[blue] (axis cs: 28,131) -- (axis cs: 28,131)node[anchor=east,rotate=90]{Some label};
            %\draw (axis cs:28,axis cs:131);

            %\addplot[solid, purple, latex-latex]
            %coordinates{(28,0) (28,131)};

            \addplot[color=purple,mark=triangle*,mark size=2,style={thick},mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                (11.124,0)
                (11.124,200)
            };
            \node at (axis cs:38,500) {Downtime: 92 ms};

            %title={Fig. 1.Live Migration Process with Bw=131Mbps},
            \end{axis}
            %title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: When providing code, if a line is commented out, it's not something you want to be used in the output and probably not something we need to see either.  Sounds to me like this will be answered by [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/106162) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/106162) though.

Comment: ah come on leave at least the comments alone

Comment: I guess that https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/106162 answers this, but it's not entirely clear. Either way, I'm going to vote to close, please do edit your question and ping me in a comment if this is still a problem.